# Is there a nice way to import a pack of methods from a file to a class component without any binding?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I'm curious if there is some comfortable way to get access to all the methods inside a file without setting up a huge list of bindings for each one needed method from it.

Directly in class component you could do something like

```
`functionName = () => {/**code here**/}`
```

to get rid of the bind, but I can't seem to google anything that would satisfy me. The list of bindings in my more logic-heavy projects is immense and I'm looking to shorten unnecesary things. This one big boy hurts my eyes the most currently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's an example:

```
import { getIndexWithPage, getReportById } from './actions/api-calls';
```

Or if you want to import everything at once:

```
import * as myFunctions from './actions/api-calls';
```

Then you can call `myFunctions.getIndexWithPage` and etc but only if the functions you want are exported.

Comment: Why need Typescript?

Comment: Well, I did the asterisk import from the file, but still I needed to bind them to the class in order to modify the state, because if I used the ImportName.method instead of this.methodBind, the functions don't have access to the state in the class they are intended to work in. Is there the other way around?